# Getting following error while running oracle oracle apex 20.2 application-Forbidden The requested operation is not allowed

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Forbidden
The requested operation is not allowed

I  have created new application and getting above error while running app on local server

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Old Question, but this might help others:

Seems like the friendly URL feature introduced in APEX 20.1 is causing this issue. A workaround for me is just disabling that in the Application Definition Atrributes.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after upgrading from Oracle Apex 19.2 to Oracle Apex 20.2. I tried everything and nothing happened. I found this:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.1/htmrn/index.html#HTMRN-GUID-175AC460-3BCB-4871-A14C-5A232EDF8CAD

I'm not sure if this is the case, but I can't find any other explanation - in section 2.1.1 Oracle Database Requirement it is said that version 20.2 is compatible with database version 11.2.0.4 and above. Mine is 11.2.0.3. Probably doesn't work for that. Check your version of the database and share if you are below the required one to know if I guess correctly. If so, and you want APEX 20.2, you may need to update your database version first, if a possible.
I hope I helped.

Comment: Mine is Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production. but still facing  this issue